# Junit Test Case About Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public static int programContinueSelect() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (Y/N)");
    Scanner cin3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = cin3.nextLine();
    char c1 = s1.charAt(0);
    if(Input == 89 || Input == 121)
       {
        return 0;
       }
    else
       {
        return 1;
       }
}
```

I have read different posts about the scanner, however I still haven't solved the problem.

How could I test this kind of situation?

Comment: "_I still haven't solved the problem_" What problem? I must have missed the part where you explained what was going wrong and what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I want to create a test case. I assert the return is 0 if I enter "Y". And I could not deal with the scanner, and how could I enter the "Y" in the test case.

Comment: You should test your classes, not `java.util.Scanner`. So write a test for `checkStringInput`

Comment: Could I create a test case simulating that I enter "y" and check?

Comment: What does `checkStringInput` ?

Comment: public static boolean checkStringInput(char Input) {
  return Input == 89 || Input == 121;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the scanner within the method, pass it in with some fixed values. Then you can write tests like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("y");
    assertEquals(0, programContinueSelect(scanner));
}
```